# PopUp window for notification service using behaviour subject in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to achieve to view a popup for errors in a component with a text message from a notification service in angular 6.
I call my notification service when I catch errors.

First the notification service:

```
private _notification: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
private notification$: Observable<string> = this._notification.asObservable().pipe(
  publish(),
  refCount()
);

constructor() { }

notify(message: string) {
  this._notification.next(message);
  setTimeout(() => this._notification.next(null), 3000);
}
```

error-handler service:

```
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  handleError(error: any) {
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);
    console.log('URL: ' + router.url);

    const loggerService = this.injector.get(LoggerService);
    loggerService.log(error);

    const notificationService = this.injector.get(NotificationService);

    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      // BackEnd returns unsuccessful response codes(404,...)
      console.error('Status Code: ', error.status);
      console.error('Response body:', error.message);
      console.error('Error Message: ', error.error);

      notificationService.notify(`${error.status} - ${error.error}`);
    } else {
      // client side or network error occurred.
      console.error('Error occurred: ', error.message);
      notificationService.notify(`${error.status} - ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
}
```

So my question is how to display a popup when a new error message is fired to my notification service. I know how to subscribe the observable from notification service, but I have no idea how to combine this in a component with viewing a popup.

A simple code example or useful link would be nice :)

Many thanks in advance

Edit:
To clarify my question here an example usage scenario:

ComponentA sends a POST request to backend. If it fails, error-handler service catchs the error and sends the error message to my notification service.
And now there should be a popup message do display the error message from notification$.
So I know how to subscribe the notification$, but I don't know how to display the popup with the message from notification$.
Should I use a service for this or maybe another component or something else..?

Comment: You'll just make a component that subscribes to `notification$` eg with `async` pipe: `service.notification$ | async`

Comment: @martin Thanks for your answer. I added a detailed usage scenario for my question. As already mentioned above I know how to subscribe notification$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach is you can have a notification component sit at the root of your app and provide notification service at the app module. Notification service can remote control the visibility of the notification and message.

```
<html>
<app>
<notification message="notificationService.message" *ngIf="notficationService.active"> </notification>
</app>
<html>
```

Alternatively you can choose to adopt the dynamic component approach 
https://itnext.io/angular-create-your-own-modal-boxes-20bb663084a1

Comment: I used your approach in combination with a custom modalbox from the link - thanks for the hint :)